# How to change the Menu Item position on the Menu List

Tags: blackberry, menuitem

I am trying to add one menu item in the Menu List in BlackBerry. But the issue is, after clicking the menu button, my menu option is adding as the topmost menu and it is not coming in the focus. So i have scroll up and click that menu.

For this i have write this code to add the menu only to view the email:

```
SampleMenuItem mi = new SampleMenuItem(3);
    mi.setIcon(ImageFactory.createImage("image.png"));
    amir.addMenuItem(ApplicationMenuItemRepository.MENUITEM_EMAIL_VIEW, mi);
```

And here is my Sample Menu item class :

```
    private class SampleMenuItem extends ApplicationMenuItem {


        SampleMenuItem(ApplicationDescriptor app) {
            super(20);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return Constants.MSG_OPEN_WITH;
        }

        public Object run(Object context) {

............
  }
}
```

How can we add the menu in the middle of the menu list means change the menu position and make it focused??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SampleMenuItem` class extends `ApplicationMenuItem`. In this line:

```
super(20);
```

you are actually calling this constructor:

```
ApplicationMenuItem(int order)
```

From [the docs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/menuitem/ApplicationMenuItem.html#ApplicationMenuItem%28int%29):

> *Creates a new ApplicationMenuItem instance with provided menu position.
>
>   Parameters:
>
>       order - Display order of this item, lower numbers correspond to higher placement in the menu (relative, an entry of 0 won't necessarily result in the top most item).*

So changing the value to a higher one should place the menu item in a lower placement.

Comment: Ok..will try. But how can i make the menu focused??

Comment: There's no API for this, but you can try changing the order parameter. In regular MenuItems, the first MenuItem after the context menuitems is focused by default. For this to work it should have an ordinal >= 300000. I don't know if this could also work for ApplicationMenuItems.

Comment: And how to add the icon with the menu? There is some methods we tried to add the icon. But it is not working..